# Difficulties to understand radio buttons logic

Tags: java, jsp

I am having some difficulties while trying to understand the radio buttons logic.

I have two radio buttons and their name is FR.

From the database, I am retrieving a value which is "F" or "R".

I would like to do that If the value = F then the radio button which is Freeze to be checked else the other radio button to be chekced.

I tried to use

if FV_Value.equals("F") then I stopped where I do not know exactly how to deal with them.

Can you please help? and give me an example

Comment: Can you be more specific here?  Are we talking about direct html or are you using a widget library?

Comment: My question is, if I am having in the database two values "F" or "R".
and I have two radio buttons called freeze & release.
I if I want to retrieve the data and check the desired one based on the database value. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print the `checked` attribute whenever the button's value matches the model value.

```
<input type="radio" name="fr" value="F" ${model.fv == 'F' ? 'checked' : ''}>
<input type="radio" name="fr" value="R" ${model.fv == 'R' ? 'checked' : ''}>
```